# How can i inspect what is in POST request and the full address?

Tags: browser

I want to see what is in the list of objects in request and its full address. for example

http://mysite.com/index.jsp?name=name&username=username

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Answer (score 1):

try using firebug in mozilla firefox. Or in ie you can do that with http analyzer.